# Question: What is this while loop with this particular condition doing?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, copy, c-strings

```
char *strcpypp(char *dest, char *orig)
{
   char *tmp = dest;
   while (*dest++ = *orig++)
      ;

return tmp;
}
```

What is this function really doing?.

Comment: It's assigning origin to dest while also checking if the result is a null terminator which should end the loop

Comment: Dosen't it need == to see when '\0' is found?

Comment: No it does the assigning first then checks if the result is a 0.

Comment: In C, assignment is an expression; it yields the assigned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
char *strcpypp(char *dest, const char *orig);
```

because the string pointed to by the pointer `orig` is not being changed in the function.

The variable tmp should be declared in a for loop.

So the function will look like

```
char * strcpypp( char *dest, const char *orig )
{
    for ( char *tmp = dest; *tmp++ = *orig++; );

    return dest;
}
```

The function copies the string pointed to by the pointer orig in the character array pointed to by the pointer dest.

The value of this expression

```
*tmp++ = *orig++
```

is the value assigned to the character pointed to by the pointer tmp before incrementing the pointers `tmp` and `orig` themselves.

So if the assigning character is the terminating zero character '\0' of the string pointed to by the pointer orig then it is assigned to the character pointed to by the pointer tmp and the condition of the loop evaluates to false because the value of the whole expression is equal to zero.